# How to enable a recursive function to avoid stack overflow?

Tags: c++, recursion

If I have a recursive function in Java, I can call it infinitely with the following code:

```
void recfunction()
{
    recfunction();
    System.gc();
}
```

How can I do this in C++?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: You can do this in Java? Well, in C++, the above code, technically, is 'infinite', but, in practice will quickly exhaust your stack and crash. Not sure what the point of it is.

Comment: i have a function for a project, this can call itself 56000 times but should call itself over million times. how can i do this?

Comment: Get rid of the recursion.

Comment: increase the stack size `ulimit -s unlimited`; you'll crash _later_

Comment: C++ has no notion of stack space, it's an implementation detail. I would be shocked if any platform offered such a function. No implementation of c++ uses garbage collection and "cleaning the stack" is fundamentally not something the language can support.

Comment: [I don't think you can do that in java](https://repl.it/@RyanHaining1/rererererefunction)

Comment: Is it a bad practice in c++ to use recursive functions?

Comment: And can i create something like the garbage collector myself? So somehow clean the stack?

Comment: I'm not aware of any language using a garbage collector that would clean the *stack* - garbage collectors usually only manage *heap* allocated memory

Comment: @JohnSmith you can use recursion, but this is unrelated to garbage collection which is about heap allocated objects, not the call stack.

Comment: Several misconceptions here: 1: The above breaks Java (unless the compiler optimizes out the tail recursion). Same thing happens in C++. 2: Garbage collection does not affect the stack (it cleans the heap). 3: C++ does have garbage collectors (they are just not very popular as we have a better method of cleaning up memory that is deterministic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to force a c++ compiler to perform tail-call optimisation on a recursive function.

Having said that, gcc8 with -O2 will actually perform tail-call optimisation when possible.

https://godbolt.org/z/tSDODA